# Simulating Fair Coin Toss in R

Tags: probability, simulation

I am new to R, I found the theoretical answer but need to learn how to use R for simulation.

Question:
Consider tossing three fair coins. Define X as the random variable "number of heads showing when three coins are tossed." Simulate tossing three coins 10,000 times in R. Compute the simulated mean and variance of X.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Look for binomial distribution, and the function rbinom can help you.

Comment: The first three lines of R code in my Answer are sufficient to answer your question. Additional lines are for comparison. With 10,000 iterations, you can expect about one decimal place of accuracy. Code is shown for making a histogram of the simulated PDF; red dots show exact values. Enjoy learning R! You are lucky your probability course uses it. Leave a note if you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y_i \sim$ Bernoulli$(p)$, with $p\in(0,1)$ for $i = \{1,2,3\}$.

Then $X = \mathbb{1}_{\{Y_1 = 1\}} + \mathbb{1}_{\{Y_2 = 1\}} + \mathbb{1}_{\{Y_2 = 1\}}$ is the number of heads (success) in three coin tosses.

We have that $EX = 3p$ and $VX = 3p(1-p) = 3(p-p^2)$, if the coin is fair then $p=\frac{1}{2}$ and $EX = 1.5$ and $VX = 0.75$.

This can be simulated in R like this:

```
n <- 10000; p <- 1/2

Y_1 <- rbinom(n, 1, p)  #Berloulli variable
Y_2 <- rbinom(n, 1, p)  
Y_3 <- rbinom(n, 1, p)

X <- Y_1 + Y_2 + Y_3

mean(X)
var(X)
```

Things are quicker if you know that the sum of Berloulli random variables (coin tosses) is a binomial variable, as others have stated.

Comment: Welcome to the site. A nice approach (+1) using Bernoulli RVs. Perhaps more convincing if you had shown numerical results agreeing closely with theoretical values.

Comment: Thank you, I just thought it would be easier to copy-paste the code, if there was no output, but I see your point.

Comment: Sometimes I replace `[1]`s with `##`s so pasted code will run without error messages. (Not here for fear of confusing a beginner.)

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 3;  p = 1/2
x = rbinom(10000, n, p)
mean(x);  var(x)
[1] 1.5023     # simulated E(X)
[1] 0.7394687  # simulated Var(X)
n*p; n*p*(1-p)
[1] 1.5        # exact E(X)
[1] 0.75       # exact V(X)
1.96*sd(x)/sqrt(10000)
[1] 0.0168545  # 95% margin of simulation error for E(X)

hist(x, prob=T, br=(-1:3)+.5, col="skyblue", main="Simulated PDF of BINOM(3,.5)")
i = 0:3;  pdf=dbinom(i,n,p)
points(i, pdf, pch=19, col="red")
```

[image]